# key dataset lost during training using the Hugging Face Trainer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm following the course material of Hugging Face: https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/3?fw=pt (great stuff btw!).
However now I'm running in an issue.

When I run the training and eval using the default data_collator everything goes fine. But when I use the custom whole_word_masking_data_collator it doesn't work because it misses the key "word_ids".

My data is as follows:

```
DatasetDict({
train: Dataset({
    features: ['attention_mask', 'input_ids', 'labels', 'token_type_ids', 'word_ids'],
    num_rows: 30639
})
test: Dataset({
    features: ['attention_mask', 'input_ids', 'labels', 'token_type_ids', 'word_ids'],
    num_rows: 29946
})
unsupervised: Dataset({
    features: ['attention_mask', 'input_ids', 'labels', 'token_type_ids', 'word_ids'],
    num_rows: 61465
})
})
```

When I use my whole_word_masking_data_collator as follows everything is fine:

```
whole_word_masking_data_collator([lm_datasets["train"][0]])
```

However when I use it in a trainer like this:

```
from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(
    model=masked_model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=lm_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=lm_datasets["test"],
    data_collator=whole_word_masking_data_collator,
)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: 'word_ids'
```

Which I find bizar because this key is clearly pressend in the data and the whole_word_masking_data_collator function works fine standalone.

When I checked the keys in my function I did find that the key is indeed missing. I only got these keys:

```
dict_keys(['attention_mask', 'input_ids', 'labels', 'token_type_ids'])
```

So my question is: Were in my code does the key "word_ids" go missing?

Comment: I already found where it went wrong. But I do not know how to fix it yet. It seems that the trainer ignores it. See message: The following columns in the evaluation set  don't have a corresponding argument in `BertForMaskedLM.forward` and have been ignored: word_ids.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're still facing this problem, I found the solution in the same [doc](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/3?fw=pt):

> By default, the Trainer will remove any columns that are not part of the model’s forward() method. This means that if you’re using the whole word masking collator, you’ll also need to set remove_unused_columns=False to ensure we don’t lose the word_ids column during training.

Comment: Hey thanks, I "solved" the problem by not using the Trainer anymore. It restricted some things I wanted to do so I couldn't continue with the Trainer for long anyways. But thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, by setting **remove_unused_columns=False** in Trainer args

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! How is your solution different than the one posted one year ago? Please understand this is not a discussion forum. If the previous solution worked for you and you want to make sure other people are going to find it, consider upvoting it. But do not post the same answer again.